# Replacing empty space values with another value using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, replace

I work in ArcMap 10.8.1.
I have a field which contains values in format of "x     1", "x    2", "x   1" etc. A number + one to five empty spaces and a "1" or "2". I want to replace them using the Field Calculator. So the replaced value is "x     1" -> "x_1"; "x    2" -> "x_2" and so on.

I Calculate new values with this code in Python parser:
!FieldName!.replace("     2","_2") and this doesn't work. It just replaces "2" with "_2". I need to get rid of empty spaces too. I also tried !FieldName!.replace(""     "2","_2") which returns an error.

Is there a way to type in empty values into the code?

Comment: Are you saying you could have "x.1" or "x.....1" where a dot is representing a single space character? In both cases you want it to become "x_1"?

Comment: Exactly that, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) to capture that one or more spaces to be replaced with a single underscore.

Run a field calculate as shown below on the field, in my example I have a text field called test

[image: Field Calculate]

The code is:

```py
import re
def replacespace(s):
  return re.sub(" +","_",s)
```

*Note it is a single space before the + symbol*